# Save output of a command as a variable (Windows command prompt)

Tags: windows, command-line

Say I have the command:

```
python --version > PythonVersion.txt
```

A file called `PythonVersion.txt` is created. In my case the contents are "Python 3.9.13".

Can the output of a command be saved as a variable? I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
@echo off
set "PythonVersion=python --version"
echo Your Python installation is: %PythonVersion%
```

The expected output might be `Your Python installation is: Python 3.9.13`, but of course the above script isn't valid and produces `Your Python installation is: python --version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('python --version') do @set lastline=%%a
echo.%lastline%
```

If the output is multiple lines, you might have to filter the command output with `^| find ...` to just get the line you are interested in (unless you want the last line) because `for` will loop until there are no more non-empty lines...